# Dual Boot kali and windows 10

Tags: windows-10, debian, multi-boot, uefi

I wanna make my pc to dual boot kali and windows 10, but it boots windows 10 on uefi mode and kali in legacy mode. How can I make it to give me the option to select which operating system I want to boot ? Thank you.

Comment: reinstall kali in UEFI mode, and install rEFInd or use the firmwares built-in menu (try pressing F8 or F12 at POST) to select operating system.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest separating the operating system to two different drives 
1. Enable UEFI with Legacy support in your BIOS/UEFI firmware menu 
2. install Windows 10 from a UEFI formatted thumb drive into the first HDD
3. after finishing the windows 10 setup, disconnect that drive temporary
4. install kali Linux on the second HDD using BIOS (legacy) mode 
5. reconnect the HDD drive with the windows installed 
6. change the boot option in your BIOS/UEFI firmware menu to always boot into Menu
7. reboot the computer and choose the boot drive from the menu